# What would prevent a form/ API call after switching to https?

Tags: javascript, rest

We have an installation of Drupal 7 and have a form that users can submit their email using (I believe) a REST to that worked until redirecting the website to https. If I don't force https, the form works ok- so I don't believe it has to do with white-listing the site that the form is trying to POST.

I've tried a number of things to correct, but the form will not submit. Initially I thought that removing the http and replacing with an appropriate https reference under action would work, and then I tried variations of the below code like omitting the unsecure site reference, to no effect.

Using console log, upon clicking the submit button this posts: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://secure3.convio.net/prkorg/siteCRConsAPI?luminateExtend=1.7.1&api_key=******&method=getLoginUrl&response_format=json&v=1.0. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). >  So I tried to allow for that by adding the secure site URL in iis6, but it still didn't allow it to pass. In the post the only thing I changed was the key to asterisks (though I don't think it matters unless someone had whitelisted access?).

Below is the code I have:

```
    <!-- LuminateExtend for Survey Submission -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luminateExtend/1.8.1/luminateExtend.min.js"><

    /script>

    <!-- Luminate API Examples - Using Survey Form -->
    <script>
    (function($) {
    /* defines init variables for organization */
    luminateExtend({
    apiKey: '********',
    path: {        
    nonsecure: 'http://prkorg.convio.net/site/',
    secure: 'https://secure3.convio.net/prkorg/site',
   }
   });

   $(function() {
    /* UI handlers for the Survey example */
    // if($('.survey-form').length > 0) {
    //   $('.survey-form').submit(function() {
    //     $(this).hide();
    //     $(this).before('<div class="preFooter-success"><p>' +
    //                      'Thank you for subscribing!' +
    //                    '</p></div>');
    //   });
    // }

    /* example: handle the Survey form submission */
    /* if the Survey is submitted succesfully, display a thank you message 
    */
    /* if there is an error, display it inline */
    window.submitSurveyCallback = {
    error: function(data) {
      $('.survey-form').append('<div class="email-error-message">' +
        data.errorResponse.message +
        '</div>');
      $('.survey-loading').remove();
      $('.survey-form').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data, "SUCCESS")
      if (data.submitSurveyResponse.success == 'false') {
        $('.survey-form').append('<div class="email-error-message">' +
          'There was an error with your submission :( Please try again.' +
          '</div>');
        var surveyErrors = luminateExtend.utils.ensureArray

    (data.submitSurveyResponse.errors);
        $.each(surveyErrors, function() {
          if (this.errorField) {
            $('input[name="' + this.errorField + '"]').closest('.form-group')
              .append('<div class="email-error-message">' +
                this.errorMessage +
                '</div>');
          }
        });
        $('.survey-loading').remove();
        $('.survey-form').show();
      } else {
        $('.survey-form').hide();
        $('.survey-form').before('<div class="preFooter-success"><p>' +
          'Thank you for subscribing!' +
          '</p></div>');
      }
    }
    };

    /* bind any forms with the "luminateApi" class */
    luminateExtend.api.bind();
    });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <div class="preFooter lightGrayBg">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="preFooter-description">
    <img class="preFooter-mail-icon" src="<?= $base_path . path_to_theme() ?

    >/images/pf17_mail.svg" alt="mail icon">
    <p>Subscribe to get the latest news on treatments, research and other 
    updates.</p>
    </div>
    <form class="preFooter-form luminateApi survey-form" method="POST" 

    action="https://www3.parkinson.org/site/Survey" data-luminateApi='{"callback": 

    "submitSurveyCallback", "requiresAuth": "true"}'>
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="submitSurvey">
    <input type="hidden" name="survey_id" value="formidishere">
    <label for="">Email Address</label>
    <div class="preFooter-fieldset">
    <input class="preFooter-form-input" type="email" name="cons_email" 

    id="survey-cons-email" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="cons_email_opt_in" value="true">
    <button class="preFooter-form-submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Could you please recommend how you would go about solving this, or if you see the issue explain what is not matching up?

Comment: what is `convio`? Did you entered your sites url in one of their forms somewhen? I guess you habe to change it to https too...

Comment: convio is the name of the server for Luminate Online, a  constituent database where this is supposed to register a user's email usinga  survey.

So the nonsecure should utilize an https url?

Comment: `Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing` ... seems `https://secure3.convio.net/prkorg/site` doesn't allow CORS - whereas if what you say is accurate, `http://prkorg.convio.net/site/` does

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jaromanda. Could you expand upon what you are saying?